# Where is (was) the Mormon Post Office in Utah Territory in 1860

Tags: united-states, 1860s, utah, mormon

In trying to unravel some family relations in Utah Territory, one of the source materials is the 1860 Federal Census:

[image: 1860 Federal Census Salt Lake County, Utah Territory]

Paging through that census there are several Post Offices in Salt Lake County: Union, Great Salt Lake City.

Does anyone know where the "Mormon Post Office" was located (in relation to maps of today)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy way to find census locations on a map is to consult William Thorndale and William Dollarhide's *Map Guide to the U.S. Federal Census, 1790-1920* (Baltimore: [Genealogical Publishing Company](https://genealogical.com/), 1992).

But if you want to try to plot it on the map yourself, you could look for descriptions of the districts.

The online guide at the US National Archives, [1790-1890 Federal Population Censuses - Part 1](https://www.archives.gov/research/census/microfilm-catalog/1790-1890/part-01#ca) has information about what maps and ED descriptions can be found at NARA.  The section **Enumeration District Descriptions and Maps** explains:

> An ED refers to the area assigned to a single census-taker. ED descriptions pertinent to the schedules covered by this catalog are in Descriptions of Census Enumeration Districts, 1830-1890 and 1910-1950 (T1224). Table 2, ED Descriptions, 1830-90, in T1224, explains coverage of the 17 rolls pertinent to this catalog.

after Table 2, they note:

> The title of T1224 contains a misnomer because EDs, strictly defined, were not used until the 1880 census. The early censuses used the term subdivision to refer to part of a supervisor's or marshal's division or district. Subdivisions in the early censuses comprised towns, townships, or other units comparable to MCDs.

MCDs = minor civil division (see Claire Kluskens' article from Prologue, *[Plans of Division](https://www.archives.gov/publications/prologue/2003/fall/1930-eds.html)*, which describes the 1930 Census)

In NARA's microfilm catalog for T1224, the description says it hasn't been digitized yet, but that information can be stale.  FamilySearch has T1224 available here:   [Descriptions of census geographic subdivisions, 1860 : NA T1224](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/464619?availability=Family%20History%20Library). A DP, [T1224.PDF](https://www.archives.gov/files/research/microfilm/t1224.pdf) is available for download.

The USPS' [Publication 119, Sources of Historical Information on Post Offices, Postal Employees, Mail Routes, and Mail Contractors](https://about.usps.com/publications/pub119.pdf) says:

> Lists, tables, and directories of Post Offices
> are available for nearly half of the years from 1803 to 1870

If you can find those titles online, you can see if they include a map.  For instance, Hathi Trust has a listing for [List of post offices in the United States, with the names of postmasters, on the 13th of July 1857. Also the regulations and laws of the Post Office Department. Comp. from the records of the Post Office Department, by D.D.T. Leech.](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/011567838)

Publication 119 says:

> Selected editions of the List of Post Offices in the United States,
> Table of Post Offices in the United States, Directory of Post Offices,
> and  National Five-Digit ZIP Code and Post Office Directory (titles
> vary slightly) may be available from your local library through
> inter-library loan.

Check [Worldcat.org](http://www.worldcat.org/) for libraries near you.

NARA's guide to [P.O. Reports of Site Locations, 1837 - 1950](https://www.archives.gov/research/post-offices/locations-1837-1950.html) has a section on [How to Locate the Microfilm Roll Number Containing a Site Report for a Particular Post Office](https://www.archives.gov/research/post-offices/locations-1837-1950.html#ht).  For Utah the rolls are:

> - Roll 594: Utah, Beaver - Garfield Counties
> - Roll 595: Utah, Grand - Salt Lake Counties
> - Roll 596: Utah, San Juan - Sevier Counties
> - Roll 597: Utah, Summit - Weber Counties

These rolls are part of [M1126, Post Office Department Reports of Site Locations, 1837–1950](https://www.archives.gov/research/post-offices/locations-1837-1950.html) (683 rolls); the catalog includes them as part of M1126C (200 Rolls).  A DP, [M1126.pdf](https://www.archives.gov/files/research/post-offices/m1126.pdf), is available for download.

> **M1126 has been digitized and made available online through the National Archives Catalog (National Archives Identifier [608210](https://catalog.archives.gov/id/608210)).**

Other resources:

- [*Printed Maps of Utah to 1900: An Annotated Cartobibliography* by Riley Moore Moffatt (available via BYU ScholarsArchive)](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5946&context=etd)
- Maps at the Library of Congress, such as this Rand McNally [Indexed map of Utah with a new and original compilation and index.](https://www.loc.gov/item/98688562/) published in `876 which "Shows relief by hachures, drainage, post offices, stations, counties, cities and towns, roads, and railroads with names."
- Old Maps of Utah at [Old Maps Online](https://www.oldmapsonline.org/en/Utah)

---

Update: I searched for all post offices in Salt Lake County on the USGS's [Geographic Names Information System (GNIS)](https://geonames.usgs.gov/) but I do not see a Post Office by that name in the search results (GNIS does include some historical entries).

You could try looking for historical topographic maps for the area at the USGS's Site [The National Map](https://nationalmap.gov/historical/) or by using the [USGS Historical Topographic Map Explorer](http://historicalmaps.arcgis.com/usgs/) to see if you can find nearby post offices in the county.

Further reading and more resources:

- [Mapping the census](https://www.legalgenealogist.com/2015/11/25/mapping-the-census/) by Judy G. Russell (posted Nov 25, 2015)
- Census tools at Stephen P. Morse's [One-Step Web Pages](https://stevemorse.org/)

Comment: As you can see there are no EDs on these pages, but your other references are great. Eyesight just needs to hold out

Comment: @BobE Yes, that's why NARA warns us that the title of the microfilm is misleading because the term ED wasn't in use until later. The basic idea -- dividing up an area into smaller divisions when assigning the work -- applies to all censuses, but the manner of doing so and the terms used will differ depending on the particular census year.

Comment: @BobE I've updated my answer with links to USGS' historical map collection and to GNIS,

Answer (score 5):

[@JanMurphy's response](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/14538/19) is wonderful!

Just a quick note--the P.O. Reports of Site Locations, 1837-1950, have actually been digitized and are available if you click through here:  https://catalog.archives.gov/id/608210.

In addition, looking forward to the 1880 census, a number of the people in this neighborhood (using the page number and information from your original post) are still living in close proximity to one another and are enumerated in the Mill Creek district.  This might help you narrow down your 1860 location.

Comment: Good catch! The roll for Salt Lake County is M1126 Roll 595 which is here: https://catalog.archives.gov/id/68775855 -- Very often the ordering catalog for the microcopy publications will state that a particular microfilm isn't digitized yet when it has been (the catalog description lags behind the digitization project) so as you demonstrated, it's a good idea to check the main catalog to see if the the records are available.